# "HMaster" service starts always on the master backup machine/node

Tags: hbase, hadoop2

I have installed hbase over hadoop 2 successfully. I did this using one master node and three data nodes (one of them is the master backup). I've been working on that with no problem for while until I restarted all the nodes/machines. Everything worked normally but the hmaster services run on the backup machine not the master node! ... I have restarted everything ... still the hmaster services is on the backup node.. I've shutdown the the backup node and tried to restart everything else, but the hmaster services didn't start this time .... why the hmaster stuck on the backup node? and how can I move it back to the master node?

Comment: How did you configure hadoop and hbase? Cloudera/Horton or Apache? And how did you start/stop your services?

Comment: It is Apache. 
Always I start hbase using the start-hbase.sh command and stop it using stop-hbase.sh... but one time _mistakenly_ I've restarted the host machine without stopping the services or even shutdown the VMs.